# Datadriven subscription error - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, subscription, data-driven

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Connecting to: Reporting Services...

Home folder -> I have my report: "Report1"

For "Report1" I can add Subscriptions -> Data Driven Subscription...

I go through the whole process and set a schedule to run at 12:00, 1st every month. And everything goes fine.

But then when I look at the schedule again for the Data Driven Subscription, because the report is sent at 00:00 instead of 12:00.

I go to the subscription notice the time has changed to 00:00 on 1.1.0001 (pic1)and get the following error when I want to set the schedule again(pic2):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer I got from a Microsoft Specialist: 
The SQL Server needs to be updated.